# Can I add child constructor while parent doesn't have one?

Tags: php, class

The parent doesn't have constructor. In the child, I want to hook up some function with actions outside the class, so I need a constructor. Can I just add one in the child?

Comment: yep.  try it.  it works.

Comment: "with actions outside the class, so I need a constructor" --- uhm, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

If parent has one you may add in child with `parent:: __construct();`.

If the parent class does not have one, no need to use this code in child. just add `__construct()` method.